# Cannot build Android project with IDEA Intellij: Error: java: $MODULE_DIR$/target/idea-classes: does not exist

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I keep getting this error when I attempt to make and run my Android project in Intellij:

> Error: java: $MODULE_DIR$/target/idea-classes: does not exist

I checked my `.iml` file and it includes this line:

```
<output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/idea-classes" />
```

The directory is missing from disk. If I add it manually, I get an error that `/target/generated-sources/annotations` is missing and if I repeat the process I eventually see a long list of errors pointing to missing classes in those 2 directories.

I'm using Intellij IDEA 13.0.3.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a dump file permissions issue. For some reason the `target` folder became read-only for Intellij (not so intellij after all lol). I suspect `maven` might have locked the folder and it was interrupted in the middle of some operation before it had a chance to unlock it.

So the fix is to make `target` readable and writable by Intellij.